# filled array is empty when send back to user

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, tedious

I try to get data from an azure database with SQL and for this I use tedious. When I execute the code, the array "result" gets filled up with data but when de respond sends the array "result" to the user it is empty. Why and how can I solve it? (I want to send it back in JSON format, the legth is unknown I use 5 to debug).

This is my code

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    result = []
    let rowData = {}
    const request = new Request(
        `SELECT TOP (5) [LogID]
        ,[OpdrachtID]
        ,[ChangeLog]
        ,[TimeStamp]
        ,[PersonID]
    FROM [log].[LOpdracht]`,
    function (err, rowCount, rows) {
        if (err) throw err
    })
    connection.execSql(request)

    request.on('row', function(columns){
        rowData = {}
        columns.forEach(function(column){
            rowData[column.metadata.colName] = column.value
        })
        result.push(rowData)
    })

    res.send(result)
})
```

Comment: Your `send()` occurs before the *asynchronous* `on('row, callback)` completes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding this:

```
    request.on('requestCompleted', () => {
        res.send(result)
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using [Tedious](https://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/index.html). If that is so then you can use the `'done'` event to be notified when the request has completed and all rows have been read into `result`.

```
request.on('done', () => res.send(result));
```

**Update**: As the [note](https://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/api-request.html#event_done) in the documentation points out, since you are using `execSql` you will need to listen to `doneProc` and `doneInProc` instead:

```
request.on('doneProc', () => res.send(result));
request.on('doneInProc', () => res.send(result));
```

Comment: Yes I use Tedious but this did not work for me I had to use 'requestCompleted'. but thank you for pointing me the right direction.